# Springboot app Gradle build works locally but not when deployed to Heroku

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, heroku, deployment

I have a springboot rest server that I can build with `./gradlew build -x test` works fine locally. When I push my master branch to Heroku it fails with the below stack trace.

```
-----> Gradle app detected
-----> Spring Boot detected
-----> Installing JDK 1.8... done
-----> Building Gradle app...
-----> executing ./gradlew build -x test
       Downloading https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.2-bin.zip
       ..........................................................................

       > Task :compileJava
       /tmp/build_20fcdda80fef571f4d65e4396cb813c1/src/main/java/com/edge/riskassesmentwebapp/dto/OnsiteAbandonmentDto.java:10: error: class OnSiteAbandonmentDto is public, should be declared in a file named OnSiteAbandonmentDto.java
```

... (it repeats the above error for a bunch of classes)

This is my first time deploying a springboot application to Heroku and I'm not sure how to fix the build if it works locally.

Answer (score 0):

try to rename the file *OnsiteAbandonmentDto* to *OnSiteAbandonmentDto*.

Note the difference in capitalization